# how to find Sharepoint Guid of a list

Tags: sharepoint-2007, guid

I am new to Sharepoint 2007 and I have done some google to find guid of a list which I want to use for outlook synchronization of my sharepoint project using stssync.

Can somebody please help me finding out guid of a list in sharepoint 2007.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From where? UI? Code? A WebPart? A console application? A winzip plugin?

Comment: Hi Steve, this is a testing project and I want to map to my outlook but the only thing missing is GUID of a List

Comment: You did not answer to my question. In other words, is it from code or manually by hand?

Comment: It is to be manuallly by hand not from code i.e. from browser

Answer (score 12):

The simplest way is to go the list settings.

The id of the list will be in the url.

For example:

```
https://someserver/sites/somesite/_layouts/15/listedit.aspx?List=%7B263FE49C%2D7FB3%2D4247%2D93CD%2D4AAB9770EF97%7D
```

Extract the list argument:

```
%7B263FE49C%2D7FB3%2D4247%2D93CD%2D4AAB9770EF97%7D
```

And then url decode it:

```
{263FE49C-7FB3-4247-93CD-4AAB9770EF97}
```

That's easy, and works with all version of SharePoint (actually, no SP2007 to test, but I'm confident)

Comment: HI Steve, Thanks for the answer but the issue is I have the url in this format - `https://someserver/sites/somesite/` I am not sure how can i navigate to layouts or listedit page.

Comment: As I said in my answer, go to the list settings.

Answer (score 4):

Tired of doing this in notepad, just paste URL into here:

List ID Calculator, View ID Calculator

http://www.surfpointtech.com/2013/10/14/sharepoint-list-id-and-view-id-calculator/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sharepoint Manager 2007 to find GUID via GUI
Download here http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/22762

Comment: Hi Birger, Thanks for the response but I am not server admin